# Large documents spool, but don't print

Tags: networking, printer, printing, windows-server-2008-r2, network-printer

Well - essentially I have a network printer on a Std. TCP/IP port which has been working flawlessly for the last 6 months or so. Recently though it's been (randomly) failing when trying to print large documents (in terms of MB/Page count, not physical size). Say for example, I print a 30 page PDF (roughly 150MB in size say), the document spools fine, as I have watched it, and in Event Viewer, it shows it has submitted the job successfully. Right - Windows job complete, at least how I view it.

The printer then just doesn't print it - whatsoever, it doesn't even show any signs of life. It's the same with all document types, PDF, .doc etc. I can print test pages though, and small documents fine.

So, if Windows can spool the document fine, and Event Viewer shows Windows has done it's part of the job successfully - would that straight away indicate a printer hardware fault (memory perhaps), or could there be more to this?

Comment: Have you tried a different printer?

Comment: We only have one other Laser, which works fine

Comment: Is it the same Make and Model?  Even if its not I would replace the printer that is not printing.